# 2 javascript functions conflicting

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I want the logo to fill in when the animation ends and then be able to click the logo and change its color. Currently when the animation ends the logo fills in but afterwards the color doesn't change when I click it. While the stroke is being drawn I can click inside the logo and it will change color but as soon as the animation ends it no longer changes color on click.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>

    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#F15A43;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

.st0 {
stroke-dasharray: 2100;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
-webkit-animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
-o-animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
-moz-animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
}

#logo.clickit .st0 {
fill: #000;
transistion: .8s;
}

#logo.load .st0 {
fill: #434343;
transition: .5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 2100;
}
to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var loader = document.getElementById('logo');
loader.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
this.classList.toggle('load');
}, false);

var clicker = document.querySelector('#logo');
clicker.addEventListener('click', function() {
this.classList.toggle('clickit');
});

</script>
</defs>
<path class="st0" d="M427.4,252.3c0,0,0,77.5-12.3,107.5c-12.9,31.6-51.1,39.6-51.1,39.6s-12.9,3.6-25.3,3.6
c-12.7,0-12.6-7.8-12.7-15.7c0-17.1,0-120.8,0-120.8l-0.1-46.2c0-33-11.4-33.6-12.6-33.7c-1.3,0-12.3,0.6-12.3,33.6v163.2
c0,0,0.6,29.2-25.7,29.9c-7.9,0-15.8,0-23.8,0c-9,0-18,0-26.9,0c-26.3-0.7-25.7-29.9-25.7-29.9V220.2c0-33-11-33.5-12.3-33.6
c-1.3,0-12.6,0.6-12.6,33.7l-0.1,46.2c0,0,0,103.7,0,120.8c0,7.9,0,15.7-12.7,15.7c-12.4,0-25.3-3.6-25.3-3.6s-38.2-8.1-51.1-39.6
c-12.3-30-12.3-107.5-12.3-107.5c0-160.7,38-160.7,63.4-160.7s50.7,26.7,50.7,26.7c11.1-17.9,38.3-31.5,63.4-31.7
c25.1,0.2,52.3,13.8,63.4,31.7c0,0,25.3-26.7,50.7-26.7S427.4,91.6,427.4,252.3z"/>
</svg>
```

The FULL HTML is

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div style="text-align: center; padding: 150px 0;">
          <object>
              <embed src="merchery icon.svg" width="40%" height="40%">
          </object>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include full `html` at Question?

Comment: `transistion` is a misspelling. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Why do you need two different variables for the same element. `loader` and `clicker` are both the element with `id="logo"`.

Comment: There is no element with `id` == "logo" in this HTML.  Please provide your working HTML.